# Testing callback passed to Angular Material Dialog

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, angular-material

I have dialog with form which is processed by calling a callback passed to `MAT_DIALOG_DATA`.

```
onCreateBonus() {
  this.bonusFormDialog
    .open({
      actionType: BonusAction.Create,
      customers: this.customers(),
      marketOrientation: this.marketOrientation,
      currency: this.currency(),
      error: this.bonusFacade.bonusActionDialogError,
      loading: this.bonusFacade.bonusActionDialogLoading,
      close$: this.bonusFacade.closeBonusFormDialog$,
      save: bonusControl => {
        try {
          this.bonusFacade.createBonus(getCreateBonusPayload(bonusControl));
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      }
    })
    .subscribe(() => this.bonusFacade.clearBonusActionsErrors());
}
```

Note: `bonusFormDialog` is abstraction layer to provide strict typing for all dialog types. Under the hood it uses standard `MatDialog.open`

When form is submitted `save` is called with its value

```
onSubmit() {
  this.payload.save(this.form.getRawValue());
}
```

I don't return value from `MatDialogRef.afterClosed()` because if server returns error I want to give user a chance to correct that.

I would like to test that functionality (using Spectator and Jest). Currently I struggle to test if `bonusFormDialog.open()` is called with expected object because my `saveMock` is not the same instance as in component:

```
},
    ],
    "error": [Function bound signal],
    "loading": [Function bound signal],
    "marketOrientation": "FLEET",
-   "save": [Function mockConstructor],
+   "save": [Function save],
  }
```

I also would like to test if `bonusFacde.createBonus` is called with expected argument as `save` is called from component to which I don't have access from test. I think passing the mock function and calling it won't trigger that process.